# Доступ к вложенным элементам из управляющего класса

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть такой код, описывающий вложенные списки:

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item();
private:
    int m_data1;
    int m_data2;
};

class SubGroup
{
public:
    SubGroup();
private:
    std::vector<Item> m_cont;
};

class Group
{
public:
    Group();
private:
    std::vector<SubGroup> m_cont;
};
```

**Вопрос**: как лучше получить доступ элементам `Item` (перебрать все) из управляющего класса `Manager`?

```
class Manager
{
public:
    Manager(Group &group);
};
```

Может быть есть какой то паттерн? Модификация классов списка допустима.

Comment: Нормальный путь, это метод перебора элементов в subGroup и в Group, а Manager уже эти методы использует.

Comment: как лучше зависит  от вашей задачи.  Как хотите...

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-list-in-c-stl/

Пример вашей задачи стандартными средствами STL

Comment: Уберите `private` и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как лучше?.. Решать вам, исходя из вашей задачи и намерений, но в любом случаи нужно обеспечить доступ к элементам закрытых членов. Простой пример:

```
class Item
{
    int m_data1;
    int m_data2;
public:
    int& first = m_data1,
        second = m_data2;
};

class SubGroup
{   
private:
    std::vector<Item> m_cont;
public:
    using Iter = std::vector<Item>::iterator;
    std::pair<Iter, Iter> range() 
    { return { m_cont.begin(), m_cont.end() }; }
};

class Group
{
    std::vector<SubGroup> m_cont;
public:
    using Iter = std::vector<SubGroup>::iterator;
    std::pair<Iter, Iter> range() 
    { return { m_cont.begin(), m_cont.end() }; }
};

class Manager
{
public:
    Manager(Group&);
};
Manager::Manager(Group& g)
{
    auto pG = g.range();
    auto pS = pG.first;
    while (pS != pG.second) {
        auto p = pS->range();
        auto p1 = p.first;
        while (p1 != p.second) {
            p1->first = rand() % 100;
            p1->second = rand() % 50;
            ++p1;
        }
        ++pS;
    }
}
```